# SharePoint 2010 ECMA : get name of current list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In a Content Editor web part, how do I get the current List Name via ECMA?
The Content Editor Web Part in located on the AllItems view of the list.

Trying to avoid server side code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM, ECMA and Server Side Object model does not provide this functionality I saw, but if anyone could give a better solution that would be great. The script I useed to get the ListName is as follows,

```
function getListTitle() {

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current()
oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
oListColl = oWeb.get_lists();
oList = oListColl.getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());
clientContext.load(oList);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

var s = window.location.toString().substring(0, window.location.toString().lastIndexOf('/'));
if (s.endsWith('Forms')) {
    s = s.substring(0, s.length - 6);
}
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I assume by list you mean the URL of the list as Name would be easy, oList.get_title

Regards
Pieter

Comment: Dont use this solution, it is completely bogus. So a query is executed on the client context and then a url parsing is done? Why? You dont need to execute the query to do that.

Comment: @Luis So where is your answer?